# Paypal donation tracking with progress bar

Tags: php, api, paypal, tracking, donations

I am designing and building a website for a non-profit. They want a PayPal Donate button and I'd like to be able to show how much they've raised so far.

I am not familiar enough with the PayPal API to even get close. So all I need to know is how to get the total amount donated as an integer value so that I can divide that by the amount needed and get a percentage.

Is anyone the least bit familiar with how to do this?

Comment: Some people are clamoring to move this to webmasters.SE, but it is a question about using an API which seems like programming to me.

Answer (score 3):

PayPal has a 'labs' (beta) widget for this. Have a look at https://giving.paypallabs.com/authenticate/review

Comment: Unfortunately, PayPal has removed this as of May 1st, 2013.  Even worse, they'll just be pulling down the existing ones on June 1st, 2013.  So we'll need a new answer pretty soon.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert, As the widget being removed, do you have a suggestion for an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Never played with paypal API, but they have code samples:

[Paypal Code Samples](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code)

this is their getBalance code sample:

```
require_once 'PayPal.php';
require_once 'PayPal/Profile/Handler/Array.php';
require_once 'PayPal/Profile/API.php';
require_once 'PayPal/Type/GetBalanceRequestType.php';
require_once 'PayPal/Type/GetBalanceResponseType.php';

$environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

//--------------------------------------------------
// PROFILE
//--------------------------------------------------
/**
 *                    W A R N I N G
 * Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
 * Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
 *
 * Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
 * encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
 * hat only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
 */

$handler = & ProfileHandler_Array::getInstance(array(
            'username' => 'my_api_username',
            'certificateFile' => null,
            'subject' => null,
            'environment' => $environment));

$pid = ProfileHandler::generateID();

$profile = & new APIProfile($pid, $handler);

$profile->setAPIUsername('my_api_username');
$profile->setAPIPassword('my_api_password');
$profile->setSignature('my_api_signature');
$profile->setCertificateFile('my_cert_file_path');
$profile->setEnvironment($environment);
//--------------------------------------------------

$balance_request =& PayPal::getType('GetBalanceRequestType');
$balance_request->setVersion("51.0");

$caller =& PayPal::getCallerServices($profile);

// Execute SOAP request
$response = $caller->GetBalance($get_balance_request);

switch($response->getAck()) {
    case 'Success':
    case 'SuccessWithWarning':
        // Extract the GetBalance response parameters
        $balance = $response->getBalance();
        $balance_amt = $balance->_value;
        $balance_currency_id = $balance->getattr('currencyID');

        $balance_time_stamp = $response->getBalanceTimeStamp();

        $balance_holdings = $response->getBalanceHoldings();
        $balance_holdings_amt = $balance_holdings->_value;
        $balance_holdings_currency_id = $balance_holdings->getattr('currencyID');

        exit('GetBalance Completed Successfully: ' . print_r($response, true));

    default:
        exit('GetBalance failed: ' . print_r($response, true));
}

?>
```